# Single Page Application AngularJS Master Detail

Tags: html, angularjs, master-detail

I'm building a single page application using AngularJS. I want it to have a master detail appearance. Where there is a list on the side and a main view on the rest of the page showing the information for that list element.

I was wondering whether the correct way to approach this would be to use ng-route? Using ng-route I presume that I would have a url such as '/:elem' and a template url which then would display the information for that element using routeParams.

I'm having a bit of trouble just working out how all the server calls work. I have separate services for the API and the UI. So are the server calls like this:

1. The user navigates to my webpage and all the .html files are returned, including the template html files, but with no data apart from just the list of elements.
2. When the user clicks one of the elements, then another call is done to the server to retrieve the data for that element.

Thank you.

Comment: There are two things. The routing and the API calls are totally separate. With Angular all the routing is done on the front end, and all the requisite html and js files are included. When it comes to routing you load the required template in the view. 
Retrieving the data from the server can be done separately through a `$http` call to the server API, which you can execute as soon as the view loads. Does that help?